# biobert for keras version of huggingface transformers

Tags: keras, nlp, keras-layer, huggingface-transformers

(also posted in https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert/issues/98)

Hi, does anyone know how to load biobert as a keras layer using the huggingface transformers (version 2.4.1)? I tried several possibilities but none of these worked. All that I found out is how to use the pytorch version but I am interested in the keras layer version. Below are two of my attempts (I saved the biobert files into folder "biobert_v1.1_pubmed").

#### Attempt 1:

```
biobert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
biobert_model.load_weights('biobert_v1.1_pubmed/model.ckpt-1000000')
```

Error message:

```
AssertionError: Some objects had attributes which were not restored:
    : ['tf_bert_model_4/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight']
    : ['tf_bert_model_4/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings/embeddings']
   (and many more lines like above...)
```

#### Attempt 2:

```
biobert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("biobert_v1.1_pubmed/model.ckpt-1000000", config='biobert_v1.1_pubmed/bert_config.json')
```

Error message:

```
NotImplementedError: Weights may only be loaded based on topology into Models when loading TensorFlow-formatted weights (got by_name=True to load_weights).
```

Any help appreciated! My experience with huggingface's transformers library is almost zero. I also tried to load the following two models but it seems they only support the pytorch version.

- https://huggingface.co/monologg/biobert_v1.1_pubmed
- https://huggingface.co/adamlin/NCBI_BERT_pubmed_mimic_uncased_base_transformers

Comment: Which version of `transformers` are you running? Also, does it work to load the PyTorch model when you are trying to directly load it from huggingface?

Comment: @dennlinger, the version of `transformers` is 2.4.1. Not sure if the pytorch version works, all my other code is in tensorflow-keras and I cannot use the pytorch version (unless I re-implement everything else in pytorch, re-train and re-evaluate all other systems... may do this in the future if I decide to move to pytorch but not now!)

Comment: I mean the problem is that the checkpoints you are loading are *not* compatible with Huggingface, instead they are the implementation suited for the original BERT model [by Google](https://github.com/google-research/bert). Therefore, I see very little chance to load the model. If you are willing to use PyTorch, then you can export the weights from the TF model by Google to a PyTorch checkpoint, which is again compatible with Huggingface AFAIK.

Comment: I knew the weights can be converted to huggingface's pytorch version but I didn't know they cannot be converted to huggingface's tf-keras version... I'll keep trying, but thanks dennlinger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bit late but I have found a not so elegant fix to this problem. The tf bert models in the transformers library can be loaded with a PyTorch save file.

**Step 1:** Convert the tf checkpoint to a Pytorch save file with the following command (more here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/docs/source/converting_tensorflow_models.rst)

```
transformers-cli convert --model_type bert\
  --tf_checkpoint=./path/to/checkpoint_file \
  --config=./bert_config.json \
  --pytorch_dump_output=./pytorch_model.bin
```

**Step 2:** Make sure to combine the following files in a directory

- config.json - bert config file (must be renamed from bert_config.json!)
- pytorch_model.bin - the one we just converted
- vocab.txt - bert vocab file

**Step 3:** Load model from the directory we just created

```
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('./pretrained_model_dir', from_pt=True)
```

There is actually also an argument "from_tf" which, according to the documentation should work with tf style checkpoints but I can't get it to work. See: https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained